# How can I check if an element is available, then click it?

Tags: python, selenium

i just want the `while` statement displayed and selenium clicks selenium have to follow the below code, Thank you in advance.

```
while (driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'area is-available').click()):
           driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/article[1]/div/section[2]/label[2]/div[2]/span').click()
           time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, you're trying to check if the element is shown, your attempt was close, but not proper.

Here is the proper way to check if an element exists, then click it. Only using your method.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 

def check_element_exists_by_class_name(fullClassName):
    try:
       driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, fullClassName)
       return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
           return False 
    return True

while check_element_exists_by_clas_name('') == False:
      pass

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '').click()
```

Comment: Dear, I want that while the element is shown up click on another element.

Answer (score 0):

*As per my understanding, you want to check if an element exists and if it does than you want to click on another element, right?*

You can use **NoSuchElementException** to find if the element exists or not. Then, you run the result into a while loop.

From my understanding, your code should look something like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        

def check_element():
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'area is-available')
        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
                
while check_element():
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/article[1]/div/section[2]/label[2]/div[2]/span').click()
    time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me how to automate react js based website which changes class name automatically i need to click on element by class name but evry time when bot is going to the website react js is changing class name and bot is unable to click on that

Comment: Try XPATH  or CSS Selector rather than class name in By. It won't matter if class name is changed. Please do accept and upvote this answer, it solved your issue.